# Android, detecting movement with sensors with effective battery use

Tags: android, android-sensors

I'm wanting to add a feature to my app (that usually runs most of it's functionality as a service) so that it can monitor for when the device is picked up.

My plan (although I'm not sure it's the best way) is to use the accelerometer to monitor for movement.

Reading the android docs it says you should unregister the sensor as soon as you can because it can drain the battery in a few hours.

So my question is, is there a way to use the sensor efficiently so as not to drain the battery, but still detect movements of the device when it's picked up?

Or is there a better way to do this.

At the moment I'm registering the sensor like this:

```
mSensorManager.registerListener(mSensorListener, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

Comment: could you not just get the accelerometer readings every few seconds? You would have a delay, but you woudnt drain the battery that fast

Comment: I was thinking that. Would you need to use an alarmmanager to handle that (ie register/unregister each time), or can you specify the polling frequency when registering the sensor?